# CSS Variable trough Polymer (dynamically loaded) elements

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have multiple custom elements in my projects and I have a problem with css variables. In my parent element I have multiple item element with status classes. I want to manipulate the background and border color using that status classes, but I want to define the values in my parent element but somehow it not want to work.

**Here my parent element:**

```
<link rel="import" href="app-task.html" />
<dom-module id="app-task-grid">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
            overflow:hidden; background: #eee;

            --column-1-width: 80px;
            --column-3-width: 120px;
            --column-4-width: 180px;
            --column-5-width: 220px;
            --column-6-width: 100px;

            --task-background-color: #eee;
            --task-border-color: #ccc;
        }

        :host table.header {
            position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 40px; background: #DDD;
        }

        :host table.header th {
            letter-spacing: 2px; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 80%; border-left: 1px solid #aaa;

            margin: 0; padding: 0 10px;
        }

        :host th.column1 {
            width: var(--column-1-width);
        }

        :host th.column2 {
            text-align: left;
        }

        :host th.column3 {
            width: var(--column-3-width);
        }

        :host th.column4 {
            width: var(--column-4-width);
        }

        :host th.column5 {
            width: var(--column-5-width);
        }

        :host th.column6 {
            width: var(--column-6-width);
            text-align: left;
        }

        :host th.hide, :host td.hide {
            display: none;
        }

        :host th.show, :host td.show {
            display: table-cell;
        }

        :host table.header .scrollbar {
            width: 20px; border-left: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        :host .items {

            position: absolute; left: 0; top: 40px; right: 0; bottom: 0;
            overflow:hidden; overflow-y: scroll;

            margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }

        :host .items::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width:22px; border-left: 6px solid #ddd;
            background-color:#ddd;
        } 

        :host .items::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color:#aaa;
            border-left: 6px solid #ddd;
            min-height: 80px;
        }

        .waiting {
            --task-background-color: #e9d32c;
            --task-border-color: #b0a030;
        }

        .assigned {
            --task-background-color: #1b7eee;
            --task-border-color: #1357a4;
        }

        .started {
            --task-background-color: #EF6207;
            --task-border-color: #c05d1d;
        }

        .working {
            --task-background-color: #e99c2c;
            --task-border-color: #c48222;
        }

        .aborted {
            --task-background-color: #E34126;
            --task-border-color: #b72d15;
        }
    </style>

    <table class="header">
        <tr>
            <th class="column1"></th>
            <th class="column2">Column#2</th>
            <th class="column3">Column#3</th>
            <th class="column4">Column#4</th>
            <th class="column5">Column#5</th>
            <th class="column6">Column#6</th>
            <th class="scrollbar"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="items">
        <app-task id="task0" class="waiting"></app-task>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is:"app-task-grid",
        loadItems: function()
        {
            let statuses = ['waiting','assigned','started','working','aborted'];
            for(var i = 1; i<=30; i++)
            {
                let itemStatus = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random()*statuses.length)];

                let itemElement = document.createElement('APP-TASK');
                        itemElement.id = 'task'+i;
                        itemElement.classList.add(itemStatus);

                console.debug( itemElement );

                this.querySelector('.items').appendChild( itemElement );
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

**My children element:**

```
<dom-module id="app-task">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block; margin: 8px 0; padding: 0;
        }

        :host table {
            width: 100%; height: 80px;

            background-color: var(--task-background-color, #fff);

            border-bottom: 5px solid var(--task-background-color, #fff);
            border-top: 5px solid var(--task-background-color, #fff);

            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07),
                        0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06),
                        0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        :host table td {
            border-left: 1px solid var(--task-border-color, #ccc);
            margin: 0; padding: 0 10px;
        }

        :host td.column1 {
            width: var(--column-1-width);
        }

        :host td.column2 {

        }

        :host td.column3 {
            width: var(--column-3-width);
        }

        :host td.column4 {
            width: var(--column-4-width);
        }

        :host td.column5 {
            width: var(--column-5-width);
        }

        :host td.column6 {
            width: var(--column-6-width);
        }
    </style>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">C#1</td>
            <td class="column2">C#2</td>
            <td class="column3">C#3</td>
            <td class="column4">C#4</td>
            <td class="column5">C#5</td>
            <td class="column6">C#6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is:"app-task"
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

**I tried already:**

- :host .waiting { ... }
- :host app-task.waiting { ... }
- app-task.waiting { ... }
- :root .waiting { ... }
- :root app-task.waiting { ... }
- :root { .waiting { ... } }
- :root { app-task.waiting { ... } }
- parent element for the app-task for the classes
- style is="custom-style" inside the app-grid template
- style is="custom-style" outside the template but inside the app-grid element html file

but none of them seems working.

If I define the css variables in the :host then it's working, only not working with classes somehow. Where did made a mistake?

---

**UPDATE#1:**

Something weird hapening with the style-scope, if I add the "style-scope app-task-grid" to the parent element for the tasks:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="style-scope app-task-grid waiting">
        <app-task id="task1"></app-task>
    </div>
</div>
```

then if I add a normal css rule like a color its applied in the app-task, but the css variables are not.

---

**UPDATE#2:**

As it was mention that this template is working, and I tested it and it is, !But id did not mention that the items are created on the fly and appended to the items. I added almost everything from my code on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/b5XW1w3sEOy4UHc0rdWH?p=preview

Sorry about my mislead, I did not know that the problem source was the dynamic load.

Note: I updated the question with more example.

---

**UPDATE#3:**

Thanks to @a1626s and @GünterZöchbauer we found the answer:

My initial code was good and worked from the beginning, I defined the questions badly becasue I did not see what was the problem. So if somebody dynamically load elements inside an element must use Polymer.dom api.

```
Polymer.dom(this.querySelector('.items')).appendCild(itemElement);
```

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer almost! now I have an effect, but it only apply the last one of the classes. Seems the variables are overwrited themselfs

Comment: I guess you need to call `Polymer.updateStyles()` or `this.updateStyles()` after you modify the DOM.

Comment: I was wrong about the problem nature, it wont work if you dinamicley create the items, sorry for the mislead!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried to add after I modified the elements, but no effect.

Comment: You need to use `Polymer.dom(...)` API if you modify the DOM when you are using shady DOM http://plnkr.co/edit/1ePGpZJeeaaVb7K8YdTv?p=preview This way you don't even need `updateStyles()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I looked the updateStyles and if I manually add the css properties with javascript its working, so that could be the best bypass so far

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you are a hero! :D can you post the answer?

Comment: I'd prefer you accept @a1626s answer. He answered the initial question and I'm sure he had found this as well. He also provided the Plunker that made it so easy to investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem in your initial code. I copied your code and pasted it in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DzuJNtdCnK1QoNLyVqia?p=preview)

```
<style>
    :host {
        display: block;
    }

    .waiting {
        --task-background-color: #e9d32c;
        --task-border-color: #b0a030;
    }

    .assigned {
        --task-background-color: #1b7eee;
        --task-border-color: #1357a4;
    }

    .started {
        --task-background-color: #EF6207;
        --task-border-color: #c05d1d;
    }

    .working {
        --task-background-color: #e99c2c;
        --task-border-color: #c48222;
    }

    .aborted {
        --task-background-color: #E34126;
        --task-border-color: #b72d15;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="items">
        <app-task id="task1" class="waiting"></app-task>
        <app-task id="task2" class="waiting"></app-task>
        <app-task id="task3" class="working"></app-task>
        <app-task id="task4" class="working"></app-task>
        <app-task id="task5" class="assigned"></app-task>
        <app-task id="task6" class="aborted"></app-task>
    </div>
```

and it seemed to be working fine for me.

As for your new problem replace your `javascript` method with this method and it should work.

```
{
  let statuses = ['waiting','assigned','started','working','aborted'];
   for(var i = 1; i<=30; i++)
    {
     let itemStatus = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random()*statuses.length)];

     let itemElement = document.createElement('APP-TASK');
     itemElement.id = 'task'+i;
     itemElement.classList.add(itemStatus);

     console.debug( itemElement );


     Polymer.dom(this.$.items).appendChild(itemElement);

    }
    Polymer.dom.flush();
   }
```

Also, here is the change that i made in your `app-task-grid` element

```
<div class="items" id="items"> //added id attribute to the div tag
```

The problem being the way you are adding child elements they do not get properly inserted into `dom tree` of the element. Polymer has documentation on how to work with tree of its elements. You can read more about it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api)

Comment: Ahh, its working and now I know why my version is not working: I was wrong about the problem, it did not work if I load dynamically the elements to the items. I forked your plunger and updated the question with more source from my app where I have this problem now

Comment: aah! saw your updated question very late. There was no need for my update. You had your answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the `<style>` where the CSS variables are set must have `is="custom-style"` in the tag.

I've thrown together a very crude snippet to show it.

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="app-task">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: var(--task-background-color, #fff);
        border: 1px solid var(--task-border-color, #ccc);
      }
    </style>
    <div>some stuff...</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'app-task'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- Beginning of the 'parent element' -->

<style is="custom-style">
  .waiting {
    --task-background-color: #e9d32c;
    --task-border-color: #b0a030;
  }
  .assigned {
    --task-background-color: #1b7eee;
    --task-border-color: #1357a4;
  }
  .started {
    --task-background-color: #EF6207;
    --task-border-color: #c05d1d;
  }
  .working {
    --task-background-color: #e99c2c;
    --task-border-color: #c48222;
  }
  .aborted {
    --task-background-color: #E34126;
    --task-border-color: #b72d15;
  }
</style>
<div class="items">
  <app-task id="task1" class="waiting"></app-task>
  <app-task id="task2" class="waiting"></app-task>
  <app-task id="task3" class="working"></app-task>
  <app-task id="task4" class="working"></app-task>
  <app-task id="task5" class="assigned"></app-task>
  <app-task id="task6" class="aborted"></app-task>
</div>
```

Another example with it running through several elements

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="app-task">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: var(--task-background-color, #fff);
        border: 1px solid var(--task-border-color, #ccc);
      }
    </style>
    <div>some stuff...</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'app-task'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- Beginning of the 'parent element' -->

<dom-module id="app-task-grid">
  <template>
    <!-- normal styles -->
    <style>
      app-task {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 10px auto;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- custom styles -->
    <style is="custom-style">
      .waiting {
        --task-background-color: #e9d32c;
        --task-border-color: #b0a030;
      }
      .assigned {
        --task-background-color: #1b7eee;
        --task-border-color: #1357a4;
      }
      .started {
        --task-background-color: #EF6207;
        --task-border-color: #c05d1d;
      }
      .working {
        --task-background-color: #e99c2c;
        --task-border-color: #c48222;
      }
      .aborted {
        --task-background-color: #E34126;
        --task-border-color: #b72d15;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="items">
      <app-task id="task1" class="waiting"></app-task>
      <app-task id="task2" class="waiting"></app-task>
      <app-task id="task3" class="working"></app-task>
      <app-task id="task4" class="working"></app-task>
      <app-task id="task5" class="assigned"></app-task>
      <app-task id="task6" class="aborted"></app-task>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'app-task-grid'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- And now pushing it to the screen -->

<app-task-grid></app-task-grid>
```

Comment: So it's supposed to only be used outside Polymer elements?

Comment: No, you can have it within another element if you like. You just need it to be is="custom-style" (as far as I know).

Comment: Hmmm, as far as I know `is="custom-style"` is not supposed to be used inside Polymer elements.

Comment: Thats nice and I already know that solution, but I dont want to put a custom-style in my main html file, I wanted to put inside my grid element so the grid always have a default coloring shame. I tried inside the app-grid element the custom style and the effect is the same as the parent element. And it's not working inside the app-grid element.

Comment: Have a look at the second example

Comment: soon as I get Home I will check it

Comment: I found out that I was not right when I defined the question, it did work initially but when I load the items dynamically (becuase i want update the grid) then it's not working, I updated the question with more details and code.